# Vuetify sidebar menu click redirection to home page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am doing a vue.js project and used vuetify framework for UI part. Created a sidebar. I want to navigate to home screen once I click that home button. I tried but did not get anything. I want to navigate to my home screen when I click on the home button. I can try doing router outlet but it is dynamic and being updated as per the text and icon given below
Below is my layout code:

```
<template>
<v-app>
  <v-app-bar app></v-app-bar>
 <v-card>
    <v-navigation-drawer app
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
      permanent
    >
      <v-list-item class="px-2">
        <v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"></v-img>
        </v-list-item-avatar>

        <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>

        <v-btn
          icon
          @click.stop="mini = !mini"
        >
          <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-list-item>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.title"
          link
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-card>
  <v-main>
    <v-container>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-main>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
//import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    //HelloWorld,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
    drawer: true,
    items: [
      { title: "Home", icon: "mdi-home-city" },
      { title: "My Account", icon: "mdi-account" },
      { title: "Users", icon: "mdi-account-group-outline" },
    ],
    mini: false,
  }),
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click event in v-list-item and call a method on this event and within the method push the path for relative path in router.

```
      <v-list-item
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.title"
      link
      @click="routePage(item.title)"
    >
      <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>

      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
```

write a method like this

```
  routePage(page) {
    switch(page) {
     case 'Home':
this.$router.push({ path: '/', query: {} });
break;
case 'My Account':
//
break;
case 'Users':
//
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vue-router, you can pass an object or directly the route you want to go, by doing the following:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app></v-app-bar>
    <v-card>
      <v-navigation-drawer
        app
        v-model="drawer"
        :mini-variant.sync="mini"
        permanent
      >
        <v-list-item class="px-2">
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/85.jpg"></v-img>
          </v-list-item-avatar>

          <v-list-item-title>John Leider</v-list-item-title>

          <v-btn
            icon
            @click.stop="mini = !mini"
          >
            <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-list-item>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list dense>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            :to="item.to"
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>

            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-card>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
//import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    //HelloWorld,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
    drawer: true,
    items: [
      { title: "Home", icon: "mdi-home-city", to: '/' },
      { title: "My Account", icon: "mdi-account", to: '/my-account' },
      { title: "Users", icon: "mdi-account-group-outline", to: 'users' },
    ],
    mini: false,
  }),
};
</script>
```

Also in case you have objects in the route `to` element you can convert the to prop to:

```js
items: [
  { title: "Home", icon: "mdi-home-city", to: { path: '/' } },
  { title: "My Account", icon: "mdi-account", to: { route: 'my-account'} },
  { title: "Users", icon: "mdi-account-group-outline", to: { path: 'users' } },
],
```

In case you are using a different routing method, you will be able to use string only, then change `to` prop, to `href`